# What does Nietzsche mean in his metaphor about dreaming and its relationship to truth?

Tags: metaphysics, nietzsche

I am having trouble understanding the following passage completely:

In accordance with the
root meaning of his association with “brightness,” 
he is the god of light; he also rules over the beautiful
appearance of the inner fantasy world. The higher t
ruth, the perfection of this condition in contrast to
the sketchy understanding of our daily reality, as we
ll as the deep consciousness of a healing and
helping nature in sleep and dreaming, is at the same
 time the symbolic analogy to the capacity to
prophesy the truth, as well as to art in general, through which life is made possible and worth living.

Here is a link to the translation I am reading: http://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Nietzsche-The-Birth-of-Tragedy.pdf

The passage is on page 12 second paragraph that begins.

Comment: Could you please indicate in some more detail where you have difficulties to understand? - Apoll got the nickname *Phoibos* which means *shining*. He was venerated also as sun god since 6th ventury BCE. - In this text Nietzsche considers fantasy - and also dreaming -  a state to obtain deeper truth than during the normal waking state.